# Symfony2 user provider for google, facebook, yahoo, linked in,

Tags: symfony

is there any implementation of the user provider which can provide user authentication into the Symfony2 application via main social networks like (google, facebook, yahoo, linked in,...)?

Somethink like stack overflow login process...

Thank you.

Myth Rush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but the [HWIOAuthBundle](http://knpbundles.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) looks promising.

if that doesn't work, you can search for other [OAUTH bundles](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=oauth) on [KNPBundles.com](http://knpbundles.com/)